# How to display crumbs in breadcrumb once in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a particular route i want to display the breadcrumb as well as the information of an item in place of breadcrumb....I want to reuse the same components breadcrumb and crumb. However, in doing so the information of item is displayed twice since i map the crumbs (which is the url).

What i am trying to do?

```
class Breadcrumb extends React.PureComponent {
render = () => {
    const path = this.props.location.pathname;
    const crumbs = [];
    path.split('/').slice(1).forEach((part, index, parts) => {
        crumbs.push('/' + parts.slice(0, index + 1).join('/'));
    });
    return (
        <div className="classname1">
            {crumbs.map((link, i) => {
                return (
                    <Fragment key={link}>
                        <Crumb
                            link={link}
                           item_information={this.props.item_information}
                          />
                    </Fragment>);
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

}

```
class Crumb extends React.PureComponent {

render = () => {
    const link = this.props.link;
    let display = [];
    let match;
    if (link === '/') {
        crumb_display = 'home';

    } else if (match = link.match(/^\/list\/new$/)) {
        crumb_display = 'list new';

    } else if (match = link.match(/^\/list\/([^/]+)$/)) {
        if (this.props.item_information.length > 0) {
            crumb_display = 'items';
        } else {
              crumb_display = 'list';
        } }
```

}

```
  return (
        <div className="classname1">
            {this.props.item_information.length > 0 && <somecomponent info={this.props.item_information}/>}
             return (
                    <div className="class">
                    <Link to={link}>{item.name}</Link>
                         </div>

                );
            })}
            <div className="class">
                <Link to={link}>{crumb_display}</Link>
            </div>
};}
```

Consider the url "/list/id"
now crumbs variable will have "/list" and "/list/id"
and since we have the crumbs.map in breadcrumb component rendering the items_information twice.. There are certain listitems that don't have item information in that case i want the breadcrumb to be list list_item_name and for items that have information display information in place of breadcrumb like for example item_information = [{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}] so it would be first second.

With the above code works fine except rendering item_information twice for url /list/id....how can i avoid this?

Could someone guide me with this. thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a https://codesandbox.io/s/new or codepen

Comment: I suggest you look at the values stored in `crumbs`. If you build this array correctly, you shouldn't see any repetition. (Note: `forEach()` with a `push()` inside can be replaced with `map()`...and even that shouldn't be necessary since `path.split('/') should give you each element of the path anyway.)

Comment: true..but not getting it right :(

Answer (score 0):

```
const crumbs = [];
path.split('/').slice(1).forEach((part, index, parts) => {
    crumbs.push('/' + parts.slice(0, index + 1).join('/'));
});
```

This looks way more complicated than necessary. I think you can do just

```
const crumbs = path.split('/');
```

Comment: changed to above and instead of crumbs.map just used <Crumb link={crumbs}/> this says match is not a function at this line else if (match = link.match(/^\/viewer\/([^/]+)$/))

Comment: @stackoverflow_user I think you need to step back and figure out the design here. What do you want to appear on the screen? Take a minute to sketch this out with something like MSPaint. From there you can figure out how to represent the pieces as components.